# Difference between AWS EC2 T4g and T3a instance types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I saw that T4g and T3a instances from AWS EC2 are really similar, and they are roughly the same price. Is there any notable difference in performance? I noticed that the T4g uses an ARM-based processor while the T3a uses the AMD EPYC processor, but I don't know how that affects performance.

I am just hosting a basic LAMP stack for my projects, with little to no traffic.

Comment: Either is likely acceptable. Go with whichever one is cheaper and has an OS that supports all the software you need. T3a is a safe bet, been around ages. T4g are new and as a bonus one size is free for the rest of the year - from memory. You still pay for EBS / etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all those answers about "we don't know" are lazy. Because you do know what types of operations you might have in a DB and you can at least provide some information about those types of operations.

For example, we ran the tests for T3.medium vs T3.small vs T4g.medium vs T4g.small AWS RDS PostgreSQL instances and found out that all of them were very similar when it came to the speed of write/read operations when you're performing an operation that is supposed to take a short time ~ 1-5 seconds.

However, where the .medium instances (both T3 and T4) really stood out was the creation of indexes on a large table and text search through a large table. In that case both T3 and T4 .medium instances were about 2x faster than the .small instances. T3 was a bit better in our tests (like 5-10%).

So I'd say go with T3 and choose the RAM size depending on the largest table in your DB.

Comment: In my experience, t4.large offers slightly higher performance than t3.large and is also more cost-effective. Don't get confused about what t2, t3, and t4 represent; these are different generations. A new generation always provides better performance than the older one, with lower power consumption and smaller hardware, making them cheaper than their predecessors.

Comment: Additionally, t4g is an ARM-based processor, and it may not support some of the programs or scripts that you already have.

Answer (score 4):

As always, do your own benchmarks/research for your own workload. I ran the popular [Geekbench 5](https://geekbench.com) benchmark against t3.medium, t3a.medium and t4g.medium Results are below (higher score is better).

```
+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Instance type | Single Core | Multi Core |               Test result link                |
+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| t3.medium     |         731 |        845 | https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/20702082 |
| t3a.medium    |         657 |        869 | https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/20701968 |
| t4g.medium    |         754 |       1502 | https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/20701961 |
+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

We cannot possibly know how these will perform for your workload. Rent both and test. Optimize according to your requirements: cost, performance, whatever.

Despite the high level similarities, these are different CPUs. Instruction sets, compiler optimizations, cache configuration, NUMA, fab processes, thermals and boost clocks, all different. Whether these add up to a significant difference for you, that is what testing is for. But certainly the price and performance dimensions will be at least a little different.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just hosting a basic LAMP stack for my projects, with little to no traffic.

I think the key thing to understand here is that with little to no traffic, it absolutely will not make a difference and thus you should go with the cheapest (in this case t4g) option available. There are no technical constraints if nothing is going to be creating resource bottlenecks.

As @cherona pointed out some very nice metrics, there are some things that amd64 processors do better then arm64 processors, and there are some things missing from it like the raw i/o handling and things like that but it shows pretty clearly that if you can deal with arm64 builds, that it is not only cheaper but probably going to give you better overall performance as well. But all of that is again irrelevant if you aren't actually pushing the limits of anything.